I can’t stand much more of this


I can’t stand much more of this.
I can't stand much of this.
I can't stand more of this.
I can't stand of this.


In no.1, what's the part of speech of 'much' and 'more'? I think 'much' modifies 'more'.
In no.1, can I replace 'much' with 'a lot, even, far, or still':
A. I can’t stand a lot more of this.
B. I can’t stand even more of this.
C. I can’t stand far more of this.
D. I can’t stand still more of this.
In no.2, what part of speech is 'much'? an object as a pronoun?
In no.3, what part of speech is 'more'? an object as a pronoun?
In no.4, is the sentence idiomatic or grammatical?

Some of A-D are ok, but those expressions lend themselves better to positive statements. "I would like a lot more of this!"

The easy part: #4 is wrong. You include the word "of", but there is nothing that is "of" anything. You can say, "the top of the box" or "the front of the box", etc, but you can't say just "of the box".
"I can't stand much more of this" is a stock phrase, an idiom. Yes, you could substitute other words with similar meanings or meanings that would make sense in context, like "I can't stand even more of this" ... but that would sound weird because than it's not the stock phrase. Unless you were trying to make some kind of point or make a joke.
"More" is normally an adjective. "Bob has more toys than Charlie." "More" is an adjective modifying "toys". Here I guess you could say it is being used as a noun. It is not "more this" but "more of this". "Much" is then an adjective modifying "more". I'll gladly yield on this to a grammarian as I think "more" SHOULD be an adjective but that doesn't seem to work in this sentence.

Not a "grammarian", but I'd say I want more = noun, I want more money = adjective, I think more / I sleep more = adverb.

@FumbleFingers The terminology needed here is that of partitive constructions.

The short answer is yes - in the phrase "much more," the word "much" modifies "more." "Much" functions as an intensifier, increasing the degree of "more". When we say "I can't stand much more" it suggests a degree of something that we can stand before our limit is reached. In contract, if we just said "I can't stand more" (or, more idiomatically, "I can't stand any more"), that would mean our limit has already been reached.
Of the options you list, not all are idiomatic. By that I mean that native English speakers wouldn't say some of them. The concept of what is, and is not 'idiomatic' is not always straightforward. Sometimes it's just a case of being the most natural-sounding grammatical construction. But sometimes, if a phrase is an 'idiom' (that is, a saying that is almost always repeated verbatim and worked into sentences unchanged), then any deviation from it can sound unusual and awkward to native speakers.
The idiomatic expression among your list is "*I can't stand much more of this", which is what we would say while experiencing something to mean that our patience is nearly at an end. And, as I previously stated, we might also say "I can't stand any more of this" to mean that our limit has already been reached. 'Any more' would mean anything beyond what we have already experienced.
It should also be noted that, by using the pronoun "this" we are indicating something present or right in front of us, and that is why I say these would be used whilst experiencing something. If we were talking about something that had ended for now, or something being suggested in the future, we'd use "that".
These are grammatical but might fit other contexts:

I can't stand much of this (you might say this before something began, to indicate that you have a limit. Omitting 'more' suggests you haven't yet experienced any of it)
I can't stand more of this (as mentioned, it's okay, but we'd probably say "any more").

Your last option "I can't stand of this" is wrong because it's clearly missing a word. The preposition "of" is for joining the pronoun object 'this' to the determiner which you have removed. If you just said "I can't stand this", that's fine, and would mean you can't stand it at all.

But the demonstrative "this" is not a pronoun; it's a determinative in a fused determiner-head NP.

@BillJ Someone should probably explain partitive constructions here, even though the syntactic model you choose to follow in that explanation may vary; there are several to choose from.
